# Font color is black in Settings activity

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, I have two activity: Main and Settings.
While in main activity, my text in tool bar is in white, as intended, in Settings,it is black, what I don't want.

How I can change the toolbar texts?

Here is my layout for both Main and Settings:

**Main:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:title="@string/app_name" />
     ...
```

**Settings:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/settings"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  </FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and if needed, defination in manifest:

```
<application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:configChanges="uiMode"
        android:label="@string/action_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
          android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="uiMode"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

**Update**
Setting Activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
        .commit();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
  }

  public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
      setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think negative voting should not be allowed without an answer/comment.

Comment: you should specify a theme for the Settings activity

Comment: or you can create a base actiivty with the given theme and inherit bothe settings and main activity from there.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a theme for your settings activity, change your manifest to this

```
<application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:configChanges="uiMode"
        android:label="@string/action_settings"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
          android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="uiMode"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: That removes the appbar from settings screen. My setting Activity onCreate is added.

Comment: ok, try out different themes or create a custom theme, also you should add the app bar layout to your settings activity

Comment: No... Its done. So, basically remove appbar, and add toolbar. The problem was, i defined androidx toolbar in layout and called android.widget toolbar in the code.